# Collision detection maths

Tags: game-engine, game-physics

[image: Collision example]

In the example above I have a red circle which sends out a straight line and various angles. How can I detect when this line intersects with the blue square with some amount of tolerance?

For example, the blue square in this example would be set at position 1,4 on the grid, however if the line intersects with 1,3.8 I would still like that to count as a hit.